# Quicklisp overriding default systems

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I have a slightly modified version of `cl-json` that I use for a poorly implemented server parser. When I try to `(ql:quickload :cl-json)` it naturally loads the file that they have stored on their server as opposed to my modified version stored on my local hard drive.

I considered turning it into an ASDF module, but all of my source code has references like `(json:decode...)` which would no longer work.

How do I tell quicklisp "Do not download from the server, instead use that directory over there"?

Comment: If the library is in `quicklisp/local-projects` or if asdf can otherwise find it, Quicklisp will load that version instead of the default. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11265601/2626993 gives an example of creating that setup.

Answer (score 4):

Quicklisp comes with a mechanism to do precisely that. Just place your version of cl-json in `~/quicklisp/local-projects/` and be done with it.

But I'm left wondering why would you think symbols that specify the package would stop to work? They won't. Or that quicklisp has anything to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find this link [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems) with the following recommendation:

> with the type conf4, for instance 42-asd-link-farm.conf, containing
> the line:
>
> (:directory "/home/luser/.asd-link-farm/")
>
> If you want all the subdirectories under /home/luser/lisp/ to be
> recursively scanned for .asd files, instead use:
>
> (:tree "/home/luser/lisp/")

Using the `(:tree ...)` command would make it easy to never worry about that again.